# Winui 3 ScrollViewer issue

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a problem with a ScrollViewer in WinUI 3. Specifically, the issue is that the ScrollViewer contains a Grid with pointerpressed events attached to it. These events draw certain elements. Now, my question is how to achieve the effect where the scroll only scrolls the content using the scrollbar, and not when touching the grid with fingers.